# UI Tests passing in XCode, Failing in Jenkins

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins, xcode-ui-testing

Whenever I run UI Tests locally, they pass, and I can watch the simulator do exactly what it's supposed to.

Then, when the tests run on Jenkins, they fail on the first line.

If it matters, this is the failure:

`UI Testing Failure - No matches found for Table`

The above error never happens when the tests are running locally.

Comment: Are you able to watch the tests run on Jenkins? Sounds like a race condition. Make sure your Jenkins has sufficient power to run the simulator at full speed.

Comment: The above question has lack of information to figure out the actual issue that is happening behind the scene. Can you please elaborate and provide some sort of example or your configuration so that people can understand and fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate all of the help, and also want to help others with the same issue as much as possible. It's tough, because I can't post code or give too much information, since the code I'm working on is proprietary.

Here was the issue:

I didn't realize that Jenkins just ran the tests on a simulator, on a computer, just like I would do on mine. I had to handle logging into the app in Jenkins' simulator, so that all of the XCUIElements were accessible.

The tests weren't passing the first line, because I wanted to tap a "Settings" button, and a user wasn't even logged in.

Please comment if I can clarify or explain further.